# Replace record projection function with lenses

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

Almost every time I make a record, I find myself adding `makeLenses ''Record` (from [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)) immediately afterwards, and I never end up actually using the projection functions that the record gives me. In fact, looking at what `makeLenses` produces (with the GHC `-ddump-splices` flag), it looks like not even it uses those projection functions, except to choose a name for the lenses it produces.

Is there some way, either through `TemplateHaskell`, or through a preprocessor, or frankly any other magic, that I could get record projection functions to be straight up Van Laarhoven lenses instead?

To be clear, that would mean that

```
data Record a b = Record { x :: a, y :: b }
```

Would generate (with [`type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html))

```
x :: forall a b c. Lens (Record a b) (Record c b) a c
x f (Record _x _y) = fmap (\x' -> Record x' _y) (f _x)

y :: forall a b c. Lens (Record a b) (Record a c) b c
y f (Record _x _y) = fmap (\ y' -> Record _x y') (f _y)
```

Instead of

```
x :: forall a b. Record a b -> a
x (Record _x _y) = _x

y :: forall a b. Record a b -> b
y (Record _x _y) = _y
```

It would not only get rid of the boilerplate `makeLenses` but also free up the namespace (since the projection functions wouldn't ever be defined).

This is such a minor thing, but since it's attached to all my records, and records aren't such a rare thing, it is really starting to get on my nerves...

Comment: Have you looked at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a GHC extensions proposal called [OverloadedRecordFields/MagicClasses](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/MagicClasses). [Adam Gundry is working on an active pull request](https://phabricator.haskell.org/D1687). It, combined with [OverloadedRecordLabels](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/OverloadedLabels), are intended to address this very problem!

```
data Foo = Foo { x :: Int, y :: Int }

class IsLabel (x :: Symbol) a where
  fromLabel :: Proxy# x -> a
```

With an example datatype like `Foo`, the subexpression `#x` in the expression `#x (foo :: Foo)`  will be magically expanded by the compiler to `fromLabel @"x" @Foo proxy#`. That @ symbol, the type application symbol, is another GHC 8-ism.

Unlike `x`, the behavior of `#x` can be modified to suit your needs. You might have it be just a regular projection function. With `OverloadedLabels` enabled, we already have access to a polymorphic projection function `getField`:

```
instance HasField name big small => IsLabel name (big -> small) where
  fromLabel proxy big = getField proxy big
```

*Or* we could satisfy the constraint with stab-style lenses:

```
instance ( Functor f
         , HasField name big small
         , UpdateField name big big' small') =>
         IsLabel name ((small -> f small') -> (big -> big')) where
  fromLabel proxy f big =
    setField proxy big <$> f (getField proxy big)
```

With such an instance you could immediately start using `#x` as a lens:

```
over #x (* 2) (Foo 1008 0) -- evaluates to Foo 2016 0
```

Comment: Ahhh... How I was hoping something like this was in the works. How lovely! Thank you very much. Will wait a day or so before accepting.

Comment: Any idea of how far along this proposal is?