# Why DuplicateRecordFields cannot have type inference?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, records

Related post: [How to disambiguate selector function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395098/how-to-disambiguate-selector-function)

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields

> However, we do not infer the type of the argument to determine the datatype, or have any way of deferring the choice to the constraint solver.

It's actually annoying that this feature is not implemented. I tried to look up multiple sources but I could not find a reason why they decide not to infer types.

Does anyone know a good reason for this? Is it because of a limitation of the current type system?

Comment: Can this be done in future release of ghc at all?

Comment: Presumably that they couldn't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will be interested in [`OverloadedRecordFields`](https://github.com/adamgundry/ghc-proposals/blob/overloaded-record-fields/proposals/0000-overloaded-record-fields.rst) which is still being implemented.

---

The current implementation is intentionally crippled, so as to not introduce too much new stuff all at once. Inferring the record projection types turns out to open a nasty can of worms (which the aforementioned extension addresses).

Consider the following GHCi interaction

```
ghci> data Record1 = Record1 { field :: Int }
ghci> data Record2 = Record2 { field :: Bool }
ghci> :t field
```

What should the type of `field` be now? Somehow,  we need a way to capture the notion of "any record with a field called `field`". To this end, `OverloadedRecordFields` introduces a new built-in type class

> The new module `GHC.Records` defines the following:
>
> ```
> class HasField (x :: k) r a | x r -> a where
>   getField :: r -> a
> ```
>
> A `HasField x r a` constraint represents the fact that `x` is a field of
>   type `a` belonging to a record type `r`. The `getField` method gives the
>   record selector function.

Then, from our example above, it is as if the following instances were magically generated by GHC (in fact that is not actually what will happen, but it is a good first approximation).

```
instance HasField "field" Record1 Int where
  getField (Record1 f) = f

instance HasField "field" Record2 Bool where
  getField (Record2 f) = f
```

If you are interested, I recommend reading the proposal. The other feature I haven't mentioned is the `IsLabel` class. Once all of this is implemented (and some more for updating records) I look forward to being able to [get my lenses for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136144/replace-record-projection-function-with-lenses) (so I can stop declaring field names starting with an underscore and enabling `TemplateHaskell` for `makeLenses`).